# LSP-gopls in Sublime Text creates go directory in $HOME instead of a custom location

Tags: go, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, gopls

I am using Sublime Text with the LSP-gopls plugin for Go development and I have a custom `GOPATH` set: `$HOME/Code/go` instead of `$HOME/go`.

However, every time I run Sublime Text, the directory `go/pkg/mod/...` is created in the `$HOME` directory. Normally, LSP-gopls should store these files in the directory specified in `$GOPATH`, but it uses the default directory.

How can it be fixed?

I'm convinced it's LSP-gopls, because this behavior disappears when I disable it, delete the directory in `$HOME`, and restart Sublime Text. I have `export GOPATH=$HOME/Code/go` in `.zshrc`. In the plugin settings, the custom path to `gopls` is set `"command" : ["/Users/user/Code/go/bin/gopls"]`.

Comment: `GOPATH` is not used in "modern" (like, 3-4 last years) Go which operates on so-called [modules](https://go.dev/ref/mod). You might want to set [`GOCACHE`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_and_test_caching) instead.

Comment: Thank you, @kostix. Your answer brought me to a decision. Turns out I needed to set `$GOMODCACHE` in LSP-golsp settings.

`"settings":{"gopls.env":{"GOMODCACHE":"/Users/user/Code/go/pkg/mod"}}`

Comment: I do not know what you're after exactly, but just in case I should note that while that setting will be respected by `gopls`, it won't be respected by `go build` (ostensibly also if somehow called from within Sublime Text), so given the limited context, it seems more sensible to override such settings on a per-user level (say, in your ~/.whateverrc). "The trick" with caching this stuff is that it's versioned and so every call to Go tooling can reuse this information as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. This is an important addition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to set `$GOMODCACHE` in LSP-golsp settings.

```
"settings": {
  "gopls.env": {"GOMODCACHE":"/Users/user/Code/go/pkg/mod"}
}
```